# jQuery shortcuts / technique for toggling classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

In jQuery, is there another way to write this?

Version 1

```
     $("#date_filter-enable").click(function() {

        $("#search_dates").removeClass("hidden");
     });

     $("#date_filter-disable").click(function() {

        $("#search_dates").addClass("hidden");
     });
```

Version 2

```
     $("input[id^=date_filter-]").click(function(e) {

        var clicked = $(e.target);
        var id = clicked.attr("id").split("-");
        var action = id[1];

        if(action == "enable")  
         $("#search_dates").removeClass("hidden");
        else
         $("#search_dates").addClass("hidden");
     });
```

I'm used to coding like this...but I want to know if there are much effective, readable, cool way of writing it...like toggling, chaining...best practices I don't know ^^

I appreciate you sharing it! ^^

Comment: Instead of `$("#search_dates").addClass("hidden");`, you might want to use `$("#search_dates").hide()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

```
$("input[id^=date_filter-]").click(function(e) {
     $("#search_dates").toggleClass("hidden");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[id^=date_filter-]").click(function(e) {
        if($(this).attr("id").split("-")[1] == "enable")  
         $("#search_dates").removeClass("hidden");
        else
         $("#search_dates").addClass("hidden");
     });
```

Comment: I intentionally created variables for splitting, cause I find this one hard for me to read...but thanks for your input! I appreciate it ^^